# Markers Flickering on OpenLayers export from qgis2web

Tags: openlayers, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

Is there a way to stop Markers/Symbols from flickering when exported to OpenLayers using qgis2web, Or a preferred marker format to use?

The problem occurs using either SVG or simple markers. They are displayed in QGIS correctly and also export to leaflet.

An example of the issue can be seen at http://ncssurveys.com/Maps/2/index.html  The problem is exactly the same using SVG markers.

QGIS and Plugin are both updated to the current builds.

Answer (score 4):

There is no fix yet, but the suggested workaround for now is to disable the declutter function by editing the output file layers/layers.js, and removing all occurences of the following line:

```
declutter: true,
```

as outlined by Tom Chadwin [here](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/608)

Thanks @TomChadwin!